# Is possible send hexadecimal data to A2DP Bluetooth Device in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, a2dp

I am developing an application on iOS that connects to a Bluetooth A2DP device but I can not send instructions in hexadecimal to make it work. Somebody could help me? I can not find information.

With AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute I can see the UID and the name of the device but not send data.

```
let route  = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    let outPort = route.outputs.first
    if let outPort = outPort {
        print("out port name:\(outPort.portName)")
   }
```

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: A2DP just carries a stream of audio bytes to the device. What do you mean "send instructions in hexadecimal"?  You may be referring to AVRCP which is used with A2DP to send metadata and respond to remote control events. This is handled by iOS and there is no direct api.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my English, when i say: "send instructions in hexadecimal", i mean: "send commands to serial port". @Paulw11 thanks

Comment: Ok. That isn’t something you can do with A2DP; that profile just carries the audio stream. I think you want to send commands via AVRCP but that isn’t available to apps on iOS. The serial port profile (SPP) also isn’t available to apps

Comment: Thanks for your quickly response @Paulw11! I saw that BLE devices have a writeValue method, but it didn't work with A2DP Bluetooth Device :( thanks for your support!

Comment: That’s correct. Core Bluetooth is only for BLE devices, not legacy profiles

Comment: Have you tried IOBluetooth at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iobluetooth

Comment: @Paulw11 we have enable MFI program can you give some code to send pause command through AVRCP ?

Comment: I don’t think mfi will help you since your hands free device won’t be mfi certified. Using mfi you can use a legacy serial port profile to communicate with an mfi peripheral that is linked to your contract

Answer (score 0):

You should check MFi and ExternalAccessory framework in order to make your device communicates with iOS A2DP.
From iOS App side, it is very high level of perspective. you only care about sending audio data using AVAudioEngine, AudioUnit, or whatever else.
Check these urls might help you
https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-2
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory