# How to stream audio and send data over Bluetooth in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, core-bluetooth

I'm developing and app for iOS which needs to connect to a Bluetooth Device. I've been able to find and connect to devices near me using CoreBluetooth and GATT profile. The writing and reading of characteristics worked as well. These values will eventually be written when a slider is moved. However, now I also need to be able to stream audio to the Bluetooth Device.

When I looked around for streaming audio over bluetooth I noticed this could be done with AVFoundation by allowing output over bluetooth. However, then the device has to use A2DP profile. But this causes the app to be unable to read/write characteristics?

I got this piece of code to read, notify and write to specific characteristics.

```
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                  error: Error?) {
    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
    for characteristic in characteristics {
      print(characteristic)
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
        if characteristic.uuid == batteryLevelCharacteristicCBUUID { peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic) }
      }
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
        if characteristic.uuid == batteryLevelCharacteristicCBUUID {
          peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
        }
      }
      if characteristic.properties.contains(.write) {
        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .write")
        if characteristic.uuid == writeTestCharacteristicCBUUID {
          print("Writing characteristic found! Trying to write now.")
          let string = "Hello World!"
          let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
          peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This question seems similar but it is mentioned that it's not possible. [Is possible send hexadecimal data to A2DP Bluetooth Device in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53546426/is-possible-send-hexadecimal-data-to-a2dp-bluetooth-device-in-swift)
However, I was thinking. If you look at a headset for example when you press buttons there has to be some data transfer. Can this somehow be used for what I want to do? But I can't seem to find any information about these signals or how to use those in my code.

So what I want is to be able to stream the audio and also send small values like percentages.

If you know any information that might help me please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need a Bluetooth chipset in your device that is capable of supporting BLE and the legacy A2DP profile simultaneously. Button presses from headsets are delivered over the AVRCP profile

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there no other way to do this? It would be preferred if I could use a regular bluetooth chip instead of a dual chip. If there is no other way, can most iPhones connect to such a dual chip?

Comment: I believe that all iPhones that support BLE (iPhone 4 and later) should be able to connect to dual chipsets since the dual mode support is a function of the peripheral, not the central

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok thank you. I'll start looking in that direction then